# Help With Dual Boot Ubuntu 14.1 and Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

So here's my problem. I used YUMI from pendrivelinux.com, and I made a Ubuntu LiveCD. I tried manually and automatically partitioning, and I ran into many problems. After rebooting after installing (which went as smooth as can be as far as I can tell), all I get is a grub console/prompt, in which many commands don't seem to work. I know a common suggestion is to use boot-repair. But when I try to use it, it says that my PC is in Legacy mode, and I need it to be out of Legacy mode. However, I can't run my LiveCD when out of Legacy mode... So here is my problem. If anyone has any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What brand/model computer. You do have to turn secure boot off with some computers, but most should boot with secure boot on. Some also require a UEFI password to enable boot from any other device in UEFI mode. Never lose that password.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system Also try a different flash drive creator. Some may work better than others.

Answer (score 2):

First, the Ubuntu images, when burned to a CD-R, should boot in either BIOS or EFI mode. If by "LiveCD" you actually mean a USB flash drive, you can copy the Ubuntu images directly (as in `sudo dd if=imagefile.iso of=/dev/sdc`, changing the source and destination as necessary) and it should boot in either BIOS or EFI mode. You can do this from your legacy-mode boot, if necessary. As oldfred says, there are many other Windows and Linux utilities that will help you create a USB flash drive from an Ubuntu image, so even if the "direct" approach doesn't work or is impractical for you, you can try another tool.

Second, you can probably get your existing installation working as follows:

1. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)
2. Prepare a boot medium from said image.
3. Boot rEFInd. (If you've not already done so, you'll need to [disable Secure Boot.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable)) It should show you a menu of boot options, including one or more Linux kernels.
4. Boot Ubuntu from rEFInd. If you used default Ubuntu options, it should boot right up. If you created a separate `/boot` partition, though, you'll need to hit F2 or Insert twice and add a `root=` option pointing to your root filesystem.
5. In Ubuntu, install any [EFI boot loader for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders) that strikes your fancy. Two relatively easy options are:

   - Install rEFInd by installing the Debian package or using the PPA referred to on the rEFInd downloads page. rEFInd will then become your default boot manager.
   - Install and run the [Boot Repair utility,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which should install the EFI version of GRUB over the BIOS version you may already have; or which will (with luck) fix whatever misconfiguration of the EFI version you might be suffering.

Answer (score 0):

The big mistake was trying to install OS in legacy mode. It have been said that it causes only more trouble.

Don't use YUMI or your Live CD wouldn't work with UEFI properly. Use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) instead. 
I just updated this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/595914#595914). It might help you.